# How can I check if an event will be raised?

Tags: vb.net, events

How can I check if an event will be raised in VB.NET? I seem to be able to do it in C#, but not in VB, even though I'm using the same syntax.

Here's my VB.NET syntax (which returns an error)

```
If [EVENT] IsNot Nothing Then
End If
```

And here's my C# syntax (works perfectly)

```
If([EVENT] != null) //If an event is not null(nothing)
{
}
```

Here's the error that the VB code returns

> "[EVENT] is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."

Comment: I believe [Event] is a reserved keyword in VB.NET hence the error. why are you wanting to check to see if a nevent is being raised?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/25/testing-events-for-nothing-null-doug-rothaus.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a strange and little known part of VB.Nets syntax which is that if you add `Event` to the end of an Events name it exposes the object in the same way as c# does so if you have an event `Foo` you can check if there are handlers with

```
If FooEvent IsNot Nothing Then
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You need that kind of syntax in C# to ensure that you don't raise an event that has no subscribers.  Necessary because that would *crash* your code with a NullReferenceException.

That's simply not necessary in VB.NET.  And not supported, as you found out.  Unlike C#, it supports the third accessor for events (beyond add and remove), it also supports the **raise** accessor.  Which you invoke by, you guessed it, the [RaiseEvent statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It can deal with an event without subscribers just fine, no need to test.